# NSArray - How to filter an array based on two properties being matched to another object in the same array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array of this object:

```
NSString *pageNumber;
NSInteger index;
NSString *textValue;
NSString *bookmark;
NSString *GUID;
```

I want to remove the duplicate objects that have the same `textValue` and `index` values. It should not look at the other properties but only these two.

EDIT: Also, to keep the values the same during the sessions, I would like to pick only the GUID that's lower in a sort for the 2 same entries.

I have used `distinctUnionOfObjects` before but it can only help me if I need to filter the duplicates by one property.

Another creative way that I thought of was to create another property in the array that's the combination of both of these properties, and then do a `distinctUnionOfObjects` on them, but it seems dirty and a hack.

What is the easiest and most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you looked into `NSPredicate`? `NSArray` has a method that lets you use predicates and they should let you do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you implement `isEqual:` and `hash` on your object, it will automatically not allow duplicate objects in an `NSSet`. You could keep the order of your objects by using an `NSOrderedSet`.

```
@implementation YourClass
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {
  if (!([self class] == [other class]))
    return NO;
  YourClass *element = other;
  if (self.index != element.index) return NO;
  if (![self.textValue isEqualToString:element.textValue]) return NO;
  return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
  NSUInteger prime = 31;
  NSUInteger hash = [[self class] hash];
  hash = hash * prime + self.index;
  hash = hash * prime + (NSUInteger)([self.textValue hash] ^ ([self.textValue hash] >> 32));
  return hash;
}
@end

uniqueObjects = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:allObjects];
```